Prove that the inequality constraints are active at the optimal solution.
Consider the following optimization problem:
$$
\begin{alignat}{3}
 & \underset{{\bf x}}{minimize} \quad & f({\bf x}) &= x_{0,0} & &  \\
 & subject~to \quad & h({\bf x}) &= \sum_{d=1}^{D} \sum_{h=1}^{H_d} x_{d,h} - n = 0 & & \\
  &  & g_d({\bf x}) &= \sum_{h=1}^{H_d} A^2_{d,h} \left(\tfrac{1}{x_{d,h}} -\tfrac{1}{N_{d,h}}\right) - x_{0,0} \leq 0, & d&=1,\ldots,D, \\    
  &  & g_{d,h}({\bf x}) &= x_{d,h} - N_{d,h} \le 0, & \qquad d&=1,\ldots,D,~ h=1,\ldots,H_d ,& &
\end{alignat}
$$
where
${\bf x} = (x_{0,0}, x_{1,1},x_{1,2},\ldots,x_{D,~H_D}) > {\bf 0}$ is the optimization variable, and
$D,~
H_1,\ldots,H_D,~
A_{1,1},A_{1,2},\ldots,A_{D,H_D},~
N_{1,1},N_{1,2},\ldots,N_{D,H_D},~
n < \sum_{d=1}^{D} \sum_{h=1}^{H_d} N_{d,h},$
are given strictly positive numbers.
I think that $g_1,\ldots,g_D$ are active constraints at the optimal ${\bf x}^*$, and I want to prove it formally. This is a convex optimization problem for which the (weak) Slater's conditions holds true and therefore the KKT conditions are necessary for the optimality. I have tried to prove that $g_1,\ldots,g_D$ are active constraints at the optimal ${\bf x}^*$ by contradiction. That is, I wanted to demonstrate that the KKT contradicts if $\exists d \in \{1,\ldots,D\}: g_d({\bf x}^*) < 0$. However, I could not make it. Maybe there is some other way to do this. Any comment is welcome. Thank you!
